# How to combine these two array into one using php?

Tags: php, arrays, database

I want to take out the data from database and store in different array so that i can plot a graph for it. But there is a problem occur when i take out the data. I just take out part of the coding.

```html
$query =mysqli_query($con,"select * from appointment WHERE L_Name='$lname' and A_Status='CONFIRMED' and EXTRACT(month FROM A_Date) = '$month' ") or die(mysqli_error()); 
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0)
{
echo "<h3 align=center style=font-size:20px;>" .$_POST['month']. "</h3>";
echo "<table width=500 cellpadding=10 border=0 align=center><tr  style='color:#FFF;background-color:#000'><td><div align='center'>Name</td><td align='center'>Total No. of Appointment</td><td align='center'>Details</td></tr>"; 
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
 $name=$row['S_Name'];
 if($tempname!=$name)
 {
  
  $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * from appointment WHERE L_Name='$lname' and A_Status='CONFIRMED' and EXTRACT(month FROM A_Date) = '$month' and S_Name='$name' ") or die(mysqli_error()); 
  
  if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0)
  {
    
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    $x=array($name);
    $no=array($count);

    echo "<tr bgcolor='#F7D358' width=60><td align=center>".$name."</td><td width=200 align=center>" .$count. "</td>"; 
    echo "<td align=center width=80><a href='view_month.php?sname=$name&num=$count&month=$month'><img src='select.jpeg' width='80' height='30'></a></td></tr>";
  
  }
  $tempname=$name;
  
 }
  
        }   

$data = array_combine($x, $no);
print_r($data);
```

the output i get is only 1 data as there should be 2 data inside the database. How can I solve it?

Current output

```
Array ( [Ken] => 1 )
```

Expected output

```
Array ( [Alice] => 2 ),
Array ( [Ken] => 1 )
```

Comment: please show your current output and expected output both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the below lines of code. You should use `array_push`, currently you are overwriting array data

```
$x=array($name);
$no=array($count);
```

You should use this instead

```
$x = array(); //declare below the loop  
$no = array(); //declare below the loop

array_push($x, $name);
array_push($no, $count);
```

> **Note: array_push()** will raise a warning if the first argument is not an array.

This is why we have to declare your variables as array first.

Comment: do u mean $x=array_push($x,$name); ?

Comment: it give me this warning : array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null , how to solve it?

Comment: @wendy i edited my answer please check it out, php wants you to first declare your arrays

Comment: @wendy this line `array_push($x, $name);` is correct not `$x=array_push($x,$name);`. the 1st parameter represents the array on which the value will be pushed on, the 2nd parameter is the value

Answer (score 0):

**array_combine** Create an array by using the elements from one "keys" array and one "values" array.

**array_merge** The array_merge() function merges one or more arrays into one array.

you can use `array_merge`

**Instead of :** `$data = array_combine($x, $no);`

**Use :** `$data =array_merge($x, $no);`

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
$x[]=$name;  /* $x must be an array in your case you are replacing old contents of $x */
$no[]=$count;
```